# Refactor a JavaScript function using Move to a new file as the default export

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, you can refactor a JavaScript function by highlighting the code, right clicking, and selecting `Refactor...` and `Move to a new file`. This creates a new file with a named export. How do I change the setting so that `Move to a new file` creates a new file with a default export?

Comment: I have searched about half of the web and not even one extension can do this, some people were writing about typescript refactor but I didn't find any solution too, maybe you should try to write to Vscode on GitHub and send them a new feature? It would be awesome

Comment: @Freestyle09 Josh Unger
Please can you add some examples of what should be final output of this refactor. I will see if I can write an extension for vscode.

Comment: @cauchy Let's say the function to be exported is the good old `Foo` function. Then the new file should have `export default function Foo` instead of `export function Foo`, and the old file should have `import Foo from './Foo'` instead of `import { Foo } from './Foo'`. Pretty simple, if you ask me... I'm also wondering why there's no option to have it that way...